# How to make menu item appear bigger height on hover?

Tags: html, css, menu

I tried to write html and css to make menu appear just like this picture.
[image]

However,I could not figure out to make an item in hover state appears a bit higher than its parents container, `<ul>` tag, as in above picture.

HTML Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navigation Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample StyleSheet:

```
nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#404040;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3696DD;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding:15px 40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #3696DD;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

Any idea, please help many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a pseudoelement to create the extra height:

*For this to work you need to remove `overflow: hidden` on `ul`, and replace it with a fixed height.

```css
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #404040;
  height: 49px; /* plus 4px for the new border */
  border-bottom: 5px solid #3696DD;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 40px 19px; /* plus 4px to bottom to keep text centred */
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  background-color: #3696DD;
}

nav ul li:hover a::after {
  background-color: #3696DD;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Great, glad to help